# Java 2D - Multi buffer not available

Tags: java, animation, graphics, awt

I am trying to render a simple animation using Java 2D API. I need double buffering to create a smooth animation.

I tried to list available graphics configuration as shown in the following code:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class GraphicsConfigurationTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice
                = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int i = 0;
        for (final GraphicsConfiguration graphicsConfiguration : graphicsDevice.getConfigurations()) {
            System.out.println(
                    i + ": multi buffer: "
                    + graphicsConfiguration.getBufferCapabilities().isMultiBufferAvailable());
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints 30 times `false`. Does it mean that double buffering is not available at all? Or can I somehow turn it on?

I am running on Ubuntu 16_04 and launching this test class using the following command

```
java -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true GraphicsConfigurationTest
```

**UPDATE**

If I try to show the animation, it flickers. I suppose that no back buffer is used because of this flickering and because of `isMultiBufferAvailable()` returning `false`.

```
final Frame frame = new Frame(graphicsConfiguration);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
graphicsConfiguration.getDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);
frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
final BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = frame.getBufferStrategy();

try {
    while (/*not done*/) {
        // wait few milliseconds for next frame
        
        // render frame
        do {
            do {
                final Graphics graphics = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
                try {
                    // draw something using grphics
                } finally {
                    graphics.dispose();
                }
            } while (bufferStrategy.contentsRestored());
            bufferStrategy.show();
        } while (bufferStrategy.contentsLost());
    }
} finally {
    graphicsConfiguration.getDevice().setFullScreenWindow(null);
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I believe when using AWT you use a BufferStrategy of the Canvas class to get double buffering. Swing is double buffered by default.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am trying to enable double buffering by calling `frame.createBufferStrategy(2)`